# How to create a view joining 2 tables?

Tags: sql-server

I've got two tables that I'm trying to create a view from.  The problem that I', having is that the column that I would join on doesn't have all of the same values in both tables.

Here are my table structures.

Table 1

```
+-----+------+-------+
| bln | thn  | qty1  |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 | 2014 |    10 |
|   1 | 2014 |    20 |
|   2 | 2014 |    30 |
|   3 | 2014 |    40 |
|   2 | 2014 |    50 |
|   4 | 2014 |    60 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

Table 2

```
+-----+------+------+
| bln | thn  | qty2 |
+-----+------+------+
|   3 | 2014 |  200 |
|   5 | 2014 |  400 |
|   2 | 2014 |  100 |
|   2 | 2014 |  500 |
|   4 | 2014 |  300 |
|   6 | 2014 |  600 |
+-----+------+------+
```

The result from the View should be:

```
+-----+------+------+------+
| bln | thn  | qty1 | qty2 |
+-----+------+------+------+
|   1 | 2014 |   30 |    0 |
|   2 | 2014 |   80 |  600 |
|   3 | 2014 |   40 |  200 |
|   4 | 2014 |   60 |  300 |
|   5 | 2014 |    0 |  400 |
|   6 | 2014 |    0 |  600 |
+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 5):

To get the result that you want, it appears that you'll need to use a [`FULL JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join). A FULL JOIN will join your 2 tables on the `bln` column but it will return data from both tables, even if the value of the column doesn't appear in both tables.

The basic syntax of the query will be:

```
select 
  bln = coalesce(t1.bln, t2.bln),
  thn = coalesce(t1.thn, t2.thn),
  qty1 = isnull(t1.qty1, 0),
  qty2 = isnull(t2.qty2, 0)
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2
  on t1.bln = t2.bln
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43c5e/4).  This will give a result of:

```
| BLN |  THN | QTY1 | QTY2 |
|-----|------|------|------|
|   1 | 2014 |   10 |    0 |
|   1 | 2014 |   20 |    0 |
|   2 | 2014 |   30 |  100 |
|   ....
|   5 | 2014 |    0 |  400 |
|   6 | 2014 |    0 |  600 |
```

You'll notice that I used a [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.110).aspx) on the columns `bln` and `thn` - this will return the first non-null value in those columns. I then used [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) on the `qty1`, and `qty2` columns to replace the `null` values returned for these columns with a zero.  You could use either `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` for these operations - I'm using both for demo purposes.

Now, since you want to get the sum of the `qty1` and `qty2` columns, you'll add the aggregate function with a group by.  I'd actually do this in a subquery for each table, otherwise you could get an elevated total for each quantity.

```
select 
  bln = coalesce(t1.bln, t2.bln),
  thn = coalesce(t1.thn, t2.thn),
  qty1 = isnull(t1.qty1, 0),
  qty2 = isnull(t2.qty2, 0)
from
(
  select bln, thn, qty1 = sum(qty1)
  from table1
  group by bln, thn
) t1
full join
(
  select bln, thn, qty2 = sum(qty2)
  from table2
  group by bln, thn
) t2
  on t1.bln = t2.bln
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43c5e/7).  This gives the result:

```
| BLN |  THN | QTY1 | QTY2 |
|-----|------|------|------|
|   1 | 2014 |   30 |    0 |
|   2 | 2014 |   80 |  600 |
|   3 | 2014 |   40 |  200 |
|   4 | 2014 |   60 |  300 |
|   5 | 2014 |    0 |  400 |
|   6 | 2014 |    0 |  600 |
```

Finally, you just use the query to create a view:

```
create view dbo.your_view as
select 
  bln = coalesce(t1.bln, t2.bln),
  thn = coalesce(t1.thn, t2.thn),
  qty1 = isnull(t1.qty1, 0),
  qty2 = isnull(t2.qty2, 0)
from
(
  select bln, thn, qty1 = sum(qty1)
  from table1
  group by bln, thn
) t1
full join
(
  select bln, thn, qty2 = sum(qty2)
  from table2
  group by bln, thn
) t2
  on t1.bln = t2.bln
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c18c7/1)